# Create Windows console user alias

Tags: windows-11, console, alias

I must create a video tutorial and I need to show the Windows terminal.

I'd like to create an alias of the console user: is this possible without creating a new user?

For example,

```
C:\Users\maryjane
```

should become:

```
C:\Users\myalias
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just about the directory name, you can make a symbolic link. As admin, run:

```
cd C:\Users
mklink /D myalias maryjane
```

Comment: It should have the effect to read Users\myalias in the terminal, so that I can record the terminal with the alias, not the current name, for privacy reasons

Comment: It works, thanks (it must be run as admin)   :-)

Comment: Ah, yes. The Users folder is not writable by normal users